# Undefined property: stdClass in my codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

### **This is my controller function**

```
public function check_orgn_mail() 
{
    $this->load->model('registrationmodel', '', TRUE);
    $omail = $this->input->post('mailid');
    $mailresult = $this->registrationmodel->check_org_mail();
    $smil = explode("@", $omail);
    $registerCompanyID = null;
    if ($mailresult) 
    {
        foreach ($mailresult as $row) 
        {
            $registerCompanyID = $row->id;
            $cmail = explode("@", $row->email);
            $acmail[] = $cmail[1];
        }
        if (in_array($smil[1], $acmail)) 
        {
            return TRUE;
        } 
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_orgn_mail', 'Invalid Organization Mail id.');
    return false;
}
```

### **This is the function in my model**

```
function check_org_mail() 
{
    $this->db->select('email','id');
    $this->db->from('customers');
    $this->db->where('status', 1);
    $query_emai = $this->db->get();
    return $query_emai->result();
}
```

### **I am getting this error**

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$id Filename:
>   controllers/registration.php

I tried some trial and error but not working. Please help me with this. Previously it was working fine but when I checked with the different mail id, it started giving this error.

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump($row);` (put it in the loop in your controller)

Comment: It gives me out put      object(stdClass)#21 (1) { ["email"]=> string(13) "bbb@gmail.com" }

Comment: Where is the `id` in `var_dump($row)`???

Comment: Is there a column 'id' in your table?

Comment: yes sir there is a column in my table named  ' id'

Comment: Your query isn't selecting the `id` column in your table, *if* it exists

Comment: ok will try checking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your select to this:

```
$this->db->select('email, id');
```

Comment: ha I knew it! it's been far to long for me an the ol' CI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
 $this->db->select('email, id');
```

All columns are supposed be a single string argument separated by commas.
You are providing multiple arguments.

Comment: now it says    Column 'customer_id' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `end_employee_master` (`name`, `lname`, `email`, `Gender`, `password`, `activation_verified`, `customer_id`, `status`) VALUES ('Swarali', 'Swarali', 'swarali.j@technooyster.com', 'Female', '827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b', '1704f95990777a4b207860e2202ee612', NULL, 1)

Comment: i think its not getting id from the table

Comment: Is customer_id the primary key of the table end_employee_master?

Comment: You are inserting the record in the table. and the customer_id is null, you can see that in the statement, and it can't be. Make sure you are setting it.

Comment: yes Mubashar i am inserting record in the table after varifying its email id

Comment: and you need to MAKE SURE, that you are inserting the customer_id as well.

Comment: Thanks mubashar,chayan, dhazelett..the problem was in query..and its working now.